# How is it possible to add our company's VAT number to our customer's receipt emails?

Tags: orders, tax, email-templates, transactional-mail

I've done a bit of research into this, and checked various suggestions, but can't locate a simple way of inserting our company's VAT number into receipts for our customer's. We have our VAT number entered in System > Configuration > General > Store Information

And we have Enable Automatic Assignment to Customer Group in System > Customer > Customer Configuration set to Yes. But still we can't get it to appear anywhere.

We've also experimented with adding a new transactional email in with some code included at the end to try to manually add the VAT number in, we've tried:

{{var order.getData(’customer_taxvat’)}}

For example, and a few other slight variations, but NOTHING get's pulled in at all :(

Any ideas on how to solve this one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you just need `{{config path="general/store_information/merchant_vat_number"}}` to display your own vat number.

--Edit

Here's the vat number I put in settings
[image: setting vat number]

Here's my template in `System/Transactional Emails`
[image: template setting]

And here's what I get when I press preview

[image: preview]

I'd check your preview first to make sure that works, then check you you've changed the template you're using in `System/Configuration/Sales Emails`

Comment: Hi @Richard no joy with this as yet sorry.... :( We are inserting this code into a section of our "New Order" email via System > Transactional Emails but as yet no change has been made to the actual emails that are being spat out for new orders. Any other ideas how to do?

Comment: I've edited the answer with a few more things to check

Answer (score 0):

Go to C:\XAMPPROOT\workspace\dark\app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf

```
public function insertConditions($page)
    {
        $page->drawLine(25, $this->y, 570, $this->y); 
        $this->y -= 100;
        $page->drawText(Mage::helper('sales')->__('VAT TIN 27740375125 V w.e.f. 01-04-2006 CST TIN 27740375125 C w.e.f. 01-04-2006'), 35, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
    }
$this->insertConditions($page); // the custom text is added here
        $this->_afterGetPdf();
        return $pdf;**
```

strong text**